# text-decoration: none; не работает для потомов

Tags: html, css

Есть html-структура:

```html
<a href="#" class="article">
    <h3>заголовок</h3>
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="https://a4files.ru/content/uploads/2017/12/bukva-D.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <p>описание блока, арарррарарарарар</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Нужно убрать подчёркивание у потомков. Проблема в том, что `text-decoration: none;` не убирает подчёркивание. Пробовал прописывать и к ссылке и к потомкам, не помогает.

Comment: Уточните вопрос - для каких именно потомков не работает? Покажите ваш CSS, подозреваю, что напутано с иерархией стилей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно в стилях для ссылки прописать `text-decoration: none`, так как по умолчанию для любой ссылки браузер прописывает ей `text-decoration: underline`

```css
a.article{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="article">
    <h3>заголовок</h3>
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="https://a4files.ru/content/uploads/2017/12/bukva-D.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <p>описание блока, арарррарарарарар</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот CSS

```css
.news .article {
    border: 1px solid #8f8f8f;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 318px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: filter 0.8s linear;
    color: initial;
}

.news .article h3 {
    font-family: Comfortaa;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.news .article p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.news .article .photo {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.news .article .photo img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transition: transform 0.8s ease-out;
}

.news .article:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.news .article:hover .photo img {
    transform: scale(1.12);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

Comment: Перенесите код в свой вопрос, это не ответ

Comment: По вашему CSS нигде не прописано свойство  text-decoration: none; пропишите это свойство к ссылкам a{ text-decoration: none;} или к класс .article{ text-decoration: none;}

Comment: Я его специально убрал, он был прописан у ссылки

Comment: блин, я не знаю почему, но сейчас заработало